# GIS for Business Data

Tags: maps, gis, geo-location, cloud

I’m not sure if this is even considered GIS which might be why I am struggling turning up results.

I am looking for cloud based software similar to Google My Maps that allow for us to handle location based information as well as tying it to multiple other datasets.

Some of the features/functionality I am looking for:

- Ability to map locations
- Ability to tie information into locations such as “what assets are at a location”
- Trip routing between locations
- Heatmaps to show proximity of interrelated locations such as a location and its nearest eligible distribution warehouse

Answer (score 0):

I created a [project](https://github.com/francesco1119/Fantail) many years ago that allowed me to save “what assets are at a location” based on Google Maps.

And then I also created [another project](https://github.com/francesco1119/OSM_to_MSSQL) which basically is the same but takes the assets from Open Street Maps.

My question is: do you already have the "assets"? Or do you need to find them from Google Maps or Open Street Maps?

Because if you already have the assets... you are already storing them somehow, right?
So you don't need a database